# could not find a part of the path

Tags: vb.net

I have a XSD file which i am using to validate XML. The problem is i get an error. The error is not thrown when i run the code in local machine. But if i run the code in integration, the error is thrown.

```
Dim strSchemaPath As String = String.Empty
    Dim xmlSettings As XmlReaderSettings = Nothing
    Dim msStream As MemoryStream = Nothing
    IsXMLValid = True
    msStream = New MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlRequest))
    strSchemaPath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "XSD\Input.xsd")
    xmlSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
    xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
    xmlSettings.Schemas.Add(Nothing, strSchemaPath)
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: could not find a part of the path. 'D:\...\XSD\Input.xsd'

Comment: Stands to reason then that the file/directory exists (and is accessible) on the local machine, but not on the server where you get the error.

Comment: I have checked in server also, file exists. if the point the code to integration and run locally. It is not throwing any error.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i set access for the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issues with access of the file. There was a issue with the files to be copied in the server path. We can manage the files in the properties. I just changed the file property to copy always and it worked.